# Finding orthonormal eigenvectors of symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Consider the symmetric matrix
\begin{equation*}
A=\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
2 & 4 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 4 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 2 & 4
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation*}
I need to find orthonormal eigenvectors of $A$. I have calculated the eigenvalues as $6$ and $2$. For eigenvalue$=6$, I found that one eigenvector is $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & -1 & -1 &\end{bmatrix}^T$. If I perform the Gram-Schmidt process to this vector as well as another vector, say $\begin{bmatrix}-1 & -1 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}^T$ I still get to linearly dependent vectors. I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The eigenvectors (shown as column vectors) for the eigenvalues $6, 6, 2, 2$ should be $$
\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$ Now convert them to orthonormal form.

Comment: Gram-Schmidt process requires *starting* from linear **independent** vectors sets, and *results* in **orthogonal** vectors sets. However the two vectors you provided are linearly dependent.

Comment: You’re starting with a pair of linearly dependent vectors, so it should come as no surprise that the G-S process gives you a linearly dependent result (you should get a zero vector at some point, in fact).